# What's wrong with my derivation of this intertemporal first order condition?

Tags: calculus, optimization

I'm reading a simple maximization problem that goes like this:

\begin{align}
\max E_0 \displaystyle\sum\limits_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t \frac{c_t^{1-\gamma}-1}{1-\gamma}
\end{align}

subject to these constraints:

\begin{align}
C_t + X_t &= A_t K^\alpha_{t-1} \\
K_t &= (1-\delta)K_{t-1}+X_t \\
X_t &\geq \Phi \bar{X}
\end{align}

where $\bar{X}, \delta, \gamma, \alpha, \beta, \Phi $ are constants. The problem lists the first order conditions, and I'm not sure how to derive this one:

\begin{align}
C_t^{-\gamma}-\lambda_t &= \beta E_t \left[ C_{t+1}^{-\gamma} \left( 1-\delta+\alpha A_{t+1} K^{\alpha-1}_t\right)-\left(1-\delta\right)\lambda_t \right]
\end{align}

Here's what I got so far. I think The Lagrangian is

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L} &= E_0\displaystyle\sum\limits_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t \left[ \frac{C_t^{1-\gamma}-1}{1-\gamma}+\lambda_t \left( A_t K^\alpha_{t-1} - C_t - X_t\right) + \lambda^{*}_t \lbrace X_t - \Phi \bar{X}\rbrace\right] \\
&= E_0\displaystyle\sum\limits_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t \left[ \frac{C_t^{1-\gamma}-1}{1-\gamma}+\lambda_t \left( A_t K^\alpha_{t-1} - C_t - K_t + (1-\delta)K_{t-1}\right) + \lambda^{*}_t \left( K_t - (1-\delta)K_{t-1} - \Phi \bar{X} \right) \right] \\
\end{align}

(the alignment is messed up so the $E_0$ should be on the same line as the second line of the Lagrangian)

So the FOC are

\begin{align}
C_t &: \beta^{t} C_{t}^{-\gamma} - \beta^{t}\lambda_{t} = 0 \\
C_{t+1} &: \beta^{t+1} E_{t}\left[C_{t+1}^{-\gamma} - \lambda_{t+1}\right] = 0 \\
K_t &: -\beta^t \lambda_t + \beta^t \lambda^*_t + \beta^{t+1} E_t \lambda_{t+1} \left[\alpha A_{t+1} K^{\alpha-1}_t + (1-\delta) \right] - \beta^{t+1} E_t \lambda^*_{t+1}\left(1-\delta \right) = 0
\end{align}

I set the first and the third equation equal to get this:

\begin{align}
\beta^{t} C_{t}^{-\gamma} - \beta^{t}\lambda_{t} &= -\beta^t \lambda_t + \beta^t \lambda^*_t + \beta^{t+1} E_t \lambda_{t+1} \left[\alpha A_{t+1} K^{\alpha-1}_t + (1-\delta) \right] - \beta^{t+1} E_t \lambda^*_{t+1}\left(1-\delta \right) \\
&= -\lambda_t + \lambda^*_t + \beta E_t \lambda_{t+1} \left[\alpha A_{t+1} K^{\alpha-1}_t + (1-\delta) \right] - \beta E_t \lambda^*_{t+1}\left(1-\delta \right) \\
&= -\lambda_t + \lambda^*_t + \beta E_t \left[C_{t+1}^{-\gamma} \left(\alpha A_{t+1} K^{\alpha-1}_t + 1-\delta\right) - \lambda^*_{t+1}\left(1-\delta \right) \right] \\
C_{t}^{-\gamma} - \lambda^*_{t} &= \beta E_t \left[C_{t+1}^{-\gamma} \left(\alpha A_{t+1} K^{\alpha-1}_t + 1-\delta\right) - \lambda^*_{t+1}\left(1-\delta \right) \right]
\end{align}

which is close, except for a difference in notation (I think I used $\lambda^*$ where the problem used $\lambda$) and the $t+1$ time index on the last $\lambda^*$.

Does any one have any hints? What am I missing?

Comment: You have forgot to include in the Lagrangean the non-negativity constraint on $X_t$, which is a separate restriction. See where this leads you (but in any case, this restriction should have a distinct multiplier). Also two small mistakes, you forgot to write the expected value  $E_t$, and also see that the production function is $A_{t+1}K_{t}^{\alpha}$, i.e. the time indices of $A$ and $K$ differ, by design.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos sorry the time indexes on A and K were typos. I fixed that. LEt me try including the non-negativity constraint on $X_t$.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Thats pretty much it except one of the time indexes is wrong, the one on the last $\lambda^*$. That actually made a lot of sense though, so I feel I'm close.

Comment: Your derivation is correct. How certain are you that the text you are reading does not contain a typo? Otherwise it wouldn't make any sense to include the current multiplier under the expected value operator (as the text does too).

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I don't know but its possible. I'm just happy I finally got it right after a while. Thanks!